# Insert on @@RowCount=0 for Update: Timed Out in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using C# along with SQL Server (tried different version, so version doesn't matter). I write a query as

```
UPDATE tblSalesVerbiage
SET SalesID = 1,
    Message = '',
    SpanishMessage = '',
    TitleName = 'VerbiageOnline6',
    isEditable = 0
WHERE TitleName = 'VerbiageOnline6' AND SalesID = 1;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [tblSalesVerbiage]
                (SalesID, Message, SpanishMessage, TitleName, isEditable)
           VALUES (1, '', '', 'VerbiageOnline6', 0);
    SELECT 1;
END
ELSE SELECT 0;
```

The query simply tries to update a row, if affected row is 0 it tries to insert it. I found based on some research that this is faster query than other method in SQL Server. However, this query is giving problem this particular table, where if the row is not already inserted or the row isn't found for update then it take more than 30 seconds to execute while running through C# code. But when run directly in SSMS it execute in jiffy less than 1 seconds maybe.

I am not sure how to debug it. I try to run similar query on other table and they seems to work well, but again, not sure why it fails on this particular table.

Table structure is basic

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSalesVerbiage](
    [VerbId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SalesId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [TitleName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SpanishMessage] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [IsEditable] [bit] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblSalesVerbiage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [VerbId] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

Any idea what might be going wrong in here?

Comment: Why not first query the database that the record is available or not and based on that insert and update accordingly.

Comment: because it means I have to run two queries and that will be slower than running one query. Plus this query has no syntax error, so it should run in same speed as normal. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MERGE` statement

```
MERGE [tblSalesVerbiage] a
using (VALUES (1,'','','VerbiageOnline6',0)) tc (SalesID, Message, SpanishMessage, TitleName, isEditable)
ON a.TitleName = tc.TitleName
   AND a.SalesID = tc.SalesID
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET Message = tc.SalesID,
             SpanishMessage = tc.SpanishMessage,
             isEditable = tc.isEditable
WHEN NOT matched THEN
  INSERT (SalesID,
          Message,
          SpanishMessage,
          TitleName,
          isEditable)
  VALUES (SalesID,
          Message,
          SpanishMessage,
          TitleName,
          isEditable);
```

Comment: I was first using MERGE, but a article on MSDN suggest that above method is faster than MERGE query, so I switch to this method. Though I understand your intend to solution, but my question is why a query fails in C# but works when run directly.